# C# server-side socket sender?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to muddle my way through setting up a server with a socket port, but I can't find any good references/examples for my situation.

Pretty much all server-side examples go:

- Listen for socket to connect
- Receive msg from client
- Reply to client
- End communications

What I want to do is:

- Listen for socket to connect
- Begin sending data intermittently (as data updates arrive)
- Continue until the connection is broken

I'm considering taking the [standard example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), simply skipping the receive, then setting up to repeatedly send (based on receiving events inside the server), but I don't have high confidence in that and I'd like to know what the standard approach to this problem is.

Also, if I want to have multiple ports open do I have to manually assign IP ports, or can than be done automagically?

Comment: Standard approach: send when you want to send, that is all.

Comment: @Jon - Yeah, that's what I thought, but you'd think there'd be ONE example somewhere that does that -- sends a clock tick, eg.

Comment: Well, it's pretty rare to have a fully one-sided conversation like that. You don't know who connected, you don't know what they want, etc.

Comment: @Jon - Looking at some other references I'm sensing that maybe expecting an ACK after each transfer is a good idea, to detect lost connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can find one of the libraries [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155282/TCP-Server-Client-Communication-Implementation). There are some samples in demo project and I think  CustomWireProtocol is a sample project that can solve your problem. You can change the client code to send continious messages to server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into [Nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) by the author of [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/).  Here's an example from a .NET binding project on github:

https://github.com/mhowlett/NNanomsg/blob/master/Example/Program.cs